# symfony - category tree

Tags: php, symfony

I need to build category tree for FancyTree (JSON format) so I do:
**Category Entity**

```
class Category
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getParent(): Category
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

**and method which building tree:**

```
public function buildCategoryTree($categories, ?int $activeCategory = null)
{
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $tmp = [
            "title" => $category->getName(),
            "expanded" => true,
            "folder" => true
        ];

        if ($category->getId() === $activeCategory)
            $tmp['active'] = true;

        if ($category->getChildren() != null)
            $tmp['children'] = $this->buildCategoryTree($category->getChildren(), $activeCategory);

        $tree[] = $tmp;
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

But I getting infinite loop - why?
I'm getting correct all childs of specified category (I don't adding it manualy) and I can without problems to iterate on it.

Comment: take a look here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: can you show us what you are passing `buildCategoryTree` the first time you call it?

Answer (score 3):

There is the Doctrine Extensions project. It has the **Tree** nested behavior that can be used to solve the problem.

URL: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/HEAD//doc/tree.md

A bundle for Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to achieve some kind of hierarchical structure like the following:

```
array (size=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=4)
      'title' => string 'title6'
      'expanded' => boolean true
      'folder' => boolean true
      'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          4 => 
            array (size=3)
              'title' => string 'title4'
              'expanded' => boolean true
              'folder' => boolean true
          3 => 
            array (size=4)
              'title' => string 'title3'
              'expanded' => boolean true
              'folder' => boolean true
              'children' => 
                array (size=1)
                  2 => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'title' => string 'title2'
                      'expanded' => boolean true
                      'folder' => boolean true
```

try something like this:

```
public function buildTree($rootCategory, &$tree, $activeCategory = null) {
        $tree = ["title" => $rootCategory->getName(),
            "expanded" => true,
            "folder" => true
        ];

        if ($rootCategory->getId() === $activeCategory)
            $tree['active'] = true;

        if (count($rootCategory->getChildren()->toArray())) {
            foreach ($rootCategory->getChildren() as $child) {
                $this->buildTree($child, $tree['children'][$child->getId()], $activeCategory);
            }
        }
    }
```

and you call it like this the first time:

`buildTree($rootCategory, $tree[$rootCategory->getId()], $activeCategoryId);`

where `$rootCategory` is the one which does not have a *parent* and `$tree` is an empty array.

Basically, you make a `void` function and pass it only the root category from which you build your tree, at the same time you are adding each node to `$tree`, which will contain the whole structure when the algorithm is done

let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

```
private function categoryTree($parent_id = null)
{
    $a=array();
    $rows = $this->findBy(array('parent' => $parent_id), array('id' => 'ASC'));

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        array_push(
            $a,
            array_filter([
                $row->getId() => $row->getName(),
                'children' => $this->categoryTree($row->getId())
            ])
        );
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
 function buildTree($categories, $parentCategory = null) {
        $branch = array();

        foreach ($categories as $element) {
            if ($element->getParent() == $parentCategory) {
                $children = buildTree($categories, $element);
                if ($children) {
                    $element->getChildren() = $children;
                }
                $branch[$element->getId()] = $element;
                unset($categories[$element->getId()]);
            }
        }
        return $branch;
    }
```

make some check of that please :

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Category {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Once you have that, accessing the parent and children should be straight forward 
    // (they will be lazy-loaded in this example as soon as you try to access them). IE:

    public function getParent() {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function getChildren() {
        return $this->children;
    }

    // ...

    // always use this to setup a new parent/child relationship
    public function addChild(Category $child) {
       $this->children[] = $child;
       $child->setParent($this);
    }

    public function setParent(Category $parent) {
       $this->parent = $parent;
    }

}
```